# A function from a matrix to its characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, continuity, characteristic-polynomial

Maybe it's a known fact, but I would like to know whether the function sending a square matrix of order $n$ to its characteristic polynomial is continuous. If this is true, there are some resources where I can find this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $det(A-\lambda I)$

Comment: @mtiano but this function is continuous?

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic polynomial is monic of degree $n$, so it has $n$ nontrivial coefficients. Therefore we can identify the image of $\phi$ with (a subspace of) $\mathbb{R}^n$; consider the map

$$\pi:\mathbb{R}[X]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_iX^i\longmapsto(c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}).$$

Now if we define $\phi(A)\in\Bbb{R}[X]$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $A$, for any $A\in M_n(\Bbb{R})$, then we get a map

$$\pi\circ\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n:A\longmapsto(c_0(A),\ldots,c_{n-1}(A)),$$

where $c_i(A)$ is the $i$-th coefficient of the chararacteristic polynomial of $A$.

Each coefficent $c_i(A)$ is a polynomial in the coefficients of $A$, so as functions the $c_i$ are polynomials (in $n\times n$ variables!). In particular they are continuous maps from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It then follows that $\phi$ is continuous, so the answer to your question is *yes*.

Answer (score 4):

The function that takes you from an $n\times n$ matrix to its characteristic polynomial is simply
$$
\begin{align}
\phi:\mathbb R^{n\times n} &\to \mathbb R[x]\\
A &\mapsto \det(A-x I_n)
\end{align}
$$

Where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  As for whether this function is "continuous", well, how do you define continuity on such a map?  What topology do we impose on $\mathbb R[x]$?

Comment: the usual of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Ah, that works.  That is, $\phi$ would effectively be a function from $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.  Not sure where to go from there though...

Comment: Maybe because det is a polynomial function, then it's continuous?

Comment: If you impose usual topology for $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then continuity is obvious. The coefficients of each power of $x$ are polynomials in entries of $A$.

Comment: @i707107 you've hit the nail on the head.  Does that make sense to you, OP?  Not only is $\det$ a polynomial function on the matrix entries: each of the coefficients of $\lambda^k$, for $k$ from $0$ and $n$, is a polynomial on the matrix entries.  By the continuity of addition and multiplication, these are continuous functions.  Since each coordinate function is continuous, $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: no, I'm sorry I didn't understand quite well, can you add this in your answer?

Comment: I tried to elaborate on i707107 and Omnomnomnom's comments, but I talk too much to fit in a comment, so I made it into another answer. My apologies

Comment: @User84559 No need to apologize. (+1) to you for a thorough answer